# I magnify to stupefy, who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I am the eye
Stories I tell are untold
I capture through my aperture
For the illumination of the expanse
I magnify to stupify
I am the eye
Who am I?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be a

> Telescope

I am the eye

> The word telescope comes from Ancient Greek and means "far-seeing"

Stories I tell are untold

> When you look at the stars, the light you see may be millions of years old, so it is like looking into the past.

I capture through my aperture

> The aperture of a telescope is the diameter of the light collecting region

For the illumination of the expanse

> Telescopes are mainly use to view extra-terrestrial objects in the expanse of space

I magnify to stupify

> A telescope magnifies objects at which it is pointed.

I am the eye

> Telescopes are like the eyes of Earth looking out towards it's surroundings.